# ArgumentException: Option not supported. (Parameter 'url') - C# MySQL Connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried looking around StackOverflow for any other questions/problems that people have had that were similar to mine, however, I didn't seem to find any with the same particular question/issue so I was hoping someone could please help me.

I am trying to create a new database (MySQL) in C# but, when I run the program to connect and create the database it always prints the following error:

ArgumentException: Option not supported. (Parameter 'url')

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    DatabaseTest.fileHandlerV2.InitialiseDB() in fileHandlerV2.cs
    DatabaseTest.MainWindow.MainWindow() in MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

I did try a new WPF application but that causes the same issue, as well as uninstalling and re-installing MySQL. I did also try a different way of creating the DB but no luck, I've had databases work with C# before, so I have no idea why it no longer works?

The code I am trying is below.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.IO;
namespace DatabaseTest
{
    internal class fileHandlerV2
    {
        public static string FilePath = "URL=file:MySQLDB";

        public static void InitialiseDB()
        {
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(FilePath))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `store`;";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 
                cmd.CommandText = "USE `store`;";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public static void CreateTable(string cmdToExecute)
        {
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(FilePath))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = $"{cmdToExecute}";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

and calling it

```
  fileHandlerV2.InitialiseDB();
  fileHandlerV2.CreateTable("create table if not exists Customers (" +
  "customerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
  "firstName varchar(255) not null, " +
  "lastName varchar(255) not null, " +
  "address varchar(255) not null,  " +
  "phoneNum varchar(50) not null, " +
  "accountBalance double unsigned not null, " +
  "primary key(customerID));");
```

I would appreciate any help!

Tried to connect to a new database created by file but on using the 'MySqlConnection' it breaks with the error saying as above, 'option not supported' It was supported to create the database and the table (assuming all went well).

Answer (score 0):

The `new MySqlConnection()` constructor takes a *connection string*. `"URL=file:MySQLDB"` is not a valid connection string, which is why you are getting the error.

A typical MySQL Connection String looks like:

```
server=my-db-server.example.com; UserID=myuser; Password=mypassword; Database=mydatabase
```

You need to know the server hosting your MySQL database, credentials to use when connecting to it, and the database you want to use. Then there are many other options to control the specifics of how the connection is made and used.

For more information, see:

- [MySQL .NET Connection String Options](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/)
- [Connector/NET Connection Options Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html)